# How to display hindi characters in PhoneGap-android

Tags: cordova

How to display hindi characters in  PhoneGap-android?how to display hindi characters in my android phone using phonegap
please tell????
i am bringing (hindi)unicode/hexadecimal characters through Apis,,,,but it is showing block
any idea??
It is working fine on iphone but not on android phone?

Comment: can you post some code for your index.html and the activity?

Comment: Have you got answer ?

Answer (score 0):

It will work in phonegap. Just use this piece of code,

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: centurySchoolbook;
            src: url(/fonts/century-schoolbook.ttf);
        }
       body {
           font-family: centurySchoolbook;
           font-size:30px;
       }
</style>
```

Set the html page format as utf-8

Comment: hello ,i tried the code,..,<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: centurySchoolbook;
            src: url('century-schoolbook.ttf');
        }
       body {
           font-family: centurySchoolbook;
           font-size:30px;
       }
       
</style>
</head>
<body>



ूब क्षेत्रों में पानी ूब क्षेत्रों



</body>

</html>

Comment: before displaying the text just convert into hexadecimal format and then try

Comment: Wha? century-schoolbook isn't devanagari